# Read two files at the same time as input from a CP

Tags: python, file

I have two files:

1. Ids :

```
4
LA58999
B45687
CH4569
BN58966
```

2. Details:

```
7
CV45365468,Mohamed,Jilali,Tanger
B45687,Fatima,AGDI,Agadir
HJ5966,Moha,GHILO,Marrakech
BN58966,Khadija,FILALI,Larache
LA58999,Dolmi,FOUAD,TanTan
HJ789985,Hanae,KADIRI,Dakhla
CH4569,Oualid,IGIT,Nador
```

and I need to read it once to get elements from Details.in which exists in Ids.in, I tried:

```
ids = []
ids_nb = int(input())
for i in range(ids):
    ids.append(input())

details_nb = int(input())
for i in range(details_nb):
    l = input().split()[0]
    if l in ids :
        print(l)
```

and in the cmd:

```
python 1st.py < Ids.in & Details.in
```

but it doesn't work!

Comment: Do you have files or repeated calls to `input()`?

Comment: You command line is flawed. Ids.in will be redirected to the standard input stream. However, the ampersand and filename following will induce an error when you try to run it like that (at least it will on Unix type systems). You should pass the two filenames as command line arguments and open them within the Python script.

Comment: Is it within bounds to use pandas to perform this? Read these into dataframes and do a `DataFrame.merge()` lickity split.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the file names as command-line arguments, you can easily read them. (And Python doesn't need to be told ahead of time how many lines there are.)

```
import sys


with open(sys.argv[1]) as idsfile:
    ids = [line.rstrip("\n") for line in idsfile]
if int(ids[0]) != len(ids)-1:
    raise ValueError("%s: Expected %s lines but got %i" % (
        sys.argv[1], ids[0], len(ids)-1))
ids = ids[1:]

with open(sys.argv[2]) as details:
    for idx, line in enumerate(details):
        if idx == 0:
            expected = int(line.rstrip("\n")
        elif line.split(",")[0] in ids:
            print(line, end="")
if idx != expected:
    raise ValueError("%s: Expected %i lines but got %i" % (
        sys.argv[2], expected, idx))
```

Usage:

```
python3 script.py Ids.in Details.in
```

(or just `python` instead of `python3` on some platforms).